# How can i measure the size of objects in an photo taken by iPhone without ARKit?

Tags: ios, opencv

we’ll be using the United States quarter as our reference object and throughout all examples

[image: we’ll be using the United States quarter as our reference object and throughout all examples]

I need to determine our “pixels per metric” ratio, which describes the number of pixels that can “fit” into a given number of inches, millimeters, meters, etc.

I need output should look something like the following:

[image: I need output should look something like the following:]

Answer (score 1):

You can find code on this [blog](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/) to find size of objects.

**Pixels per metric -**

It is defined as Number of pixels per metric (mm, cm, mtr). First you need to find this ratio for a single object ( US Quarter in your case ). You will then use this ratio to find sizes of other objects. Now to find pixels per metric in your case -

1) Filter the image and find contours.
2) Sort the contours from left to right
3) Find the Corners of the first Contour (US quarter)
4) Find the Distance between any two adjacent corners of the object in pixels
5) pixelspermetric = Distance_between_corners_in_pixels / Distance_between_corners_in_cm

For example

Suppose the distance between two adjacent corners of US Quarter is 200 pixels and actual width of coin is 0.955 inches. So,

PixelsPerMetric = 200/0.955 = 209.4240

Now you can find size of other object as - 
size = length_in_pixels/PixelsPerMetric

This ratio remains constant for a certain height (distance between object and camera). You need to calculate the ratio again if height changes.